# Se não pesquisar, não aparecer

Tags: php

Quero que o usuário pesquise o termo e só ache aquela tabela. Porém, não consigo tirar a visualização padrão (segue o print):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero que fique apenas a barra de pesquisa e os botões abaixo (tirando o Ver Todos).

Segue o script da página:

listarprocessos.php

```
<?php
require_once ('restrito.php')
    ?>
<?php
require 'conexao.php';

$termo = (isset($_GET['termo'])) ? $_GET['termo'] : '';

if (empty($termo)):

    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = 'SELECT id, numero, nome, status, setor1, setor2, data1, observ1, setor3, setor4, data2, observ2, setor5, setor6, data3, observ3, setor7, setor8, data4, observ4, setor9, setor10, data5, observ5 FROM processos';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute();
    $clientes = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

else:

    $conexao = conexao::getInstance();
    $sql = 'SELECT id, numero, nome, status, setor1, setor2, data1, observ1, setor3, setor4, data2, observ2, setor5, setor6, data3, observ3, setor7, setor8, data4, observ4, setor9, setor10, data5, observ5 FROM processos WHERE nome LIKE :nome OR numero LIKE :numero';
    $stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(':nome', $termo.'%');
    $stm->bindValue(':numero', $termo.'%');
    $stm->execute();
    $clientes = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    endif; 


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Controle de Processos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/xdxd.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/haha.scss">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/xdxd.mas.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/haha.mas.scss">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/tables.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="imagens/pref.ico">
    <style type="text/css">
body {
    background-image: url("./img/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
.xdxd {
  position: relative;
  top: -23px;
  left: 110px;
}
.xd {
    position: relative;
    left: 14px;
}
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
#myBtn {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Fixed/sticky position */
    bottom: 15px; /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
    right: 30px; /* Place the button 30px from the right */
    z-index: 99; /* Make sure it does not overlap */
    border: none; /* Remove borders */
    outline: none; /* Remove outline */
    background-color: black; /* Set a background color */
    color: white; /* Text color */
    cursor: pointer; /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
    padding: 15px; /* Some padding */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase font size */
}

#myBtn:hover {
    background-color: #555; /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
}
.botaoProxima {
    position: relative;
    left: 1350px;
}
.botaoPagina {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 1450px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


        <fieldset>
    <div class="container">
            <legend><h1 class="w3-center">Listagem de Processos</h1></legend>

            <form action="" method="get" id='form-contato' class="form-horizontal col-md-10">

                <label class="col-md-2 w3-text-black control-label" for="termo">Pesquisar</label>
                <div class='col-md-7'>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="termo" name="termo" placeholder="Informe o número ou nome do Processo">  <button type="submit" class="w3-button w3-black w3-right w3-display-right xdxd">Pesquisar</button>
                </div><br></br>


             <p>  <a href='listarprocessos.php' class="w3-button w3-black xd">Ver Todos</a>  </p>
            <p> <a href='registrarprocesso.php' class="w3-button w3-gray xd">Registrar Processo</a> </p>
            <p> <a href='http://localhost/proc/index.php' class="w3-button w3-black xd">Ir para o Site</a> </p>
            </form>


            <div class='clearfix'></div>

            <?php if(!empty($clientes)):?>
            <?php foreach($clientes as $cliente):?>
                    <table style='width:100%'>
                    <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Número</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->numero?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Nome</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->nome?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Status</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->status?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>De</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor1?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Para</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor2?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Observação de <?=$cliente->setor1?></th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->observ1?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Data</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->data1?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>De</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor3?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Para</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor4?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Observação de <?=$cliente->setor3?></th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->observ2?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Data</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->data2?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>De</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor5?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Para</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor6?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Observação de <?=$cliente->setor5?></th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->observ3?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Data</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->data3?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>De</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor7?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Para</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor8?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Observação de <?=$cliente->setor7?></th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->observ4?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Data</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->data4?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>De</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor9?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Para</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->setor10?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Observação de <?=$cliente->setor9?></th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->observ5?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Data</th>
                        <td class='w3-text-black'><?=$cliente->data5?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <th class='w3-text-black'>Ações</th>
                        <td><a href='editar.php?id=<?=$cliente->id?>' class="w3-button w3-black">Editar</a> <a href="excluir.php?id=<?=$cliente->id?>" title="Excluir o registro" class="w3-button w3-red" >Excluir</a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <BR></BR>
                    <BR></BR>

                    <tbody>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                                </tbody>
                </table>

            <?php else: ?>

                <h3 class="text-center text-primary">Não existem processos registrados!</h3>
            <?php endif; ?>         
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bom dia @Bernardo Rodel você pode trabalhar com o :
https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap<br />
Ele me ajudou bastante a resolver essa questão de visualização em tabelas e foi tranquila a utilização. <br />Esse é plugin para jQuery e fornece diversos controles de interação com tabelas HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia, se entendi o que precisas, basta repetir o if feito antes de exibir os dados da tabela.

```
<?php if(!empty($clientes)):?>
<p>  <a href='listarprocessos.php' class="w3-button w3-black xd">Ver Todos</a>  </p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Fiz isso antes e funcionou, obrigado de qualquer forma!